# Vlookup formula to pull out some data from one sheet to another (google spreadsheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets:

1. Data
2. Sheet1

I need to pull out some data from Sheet1 to Data. For this I am using the following formula:
=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$56,5,0)

It keeps giving me an error which I cannot identify.
Will really appreciate it if you could help.
Here is the link to the file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E-nBdLZI853k1avPLJ_dNEspmOiOtFj7Q5hXTFsUBDc/edit#gid=1692769539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Dear I Resolve Your VLookup

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$1:$E$56,4,0)
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E-nBdLZI853k1avPLJ_dNEspmOiOtFj7Q5hXTFsUBDc/edit#gid=1692769539